# Bash script to close open TCP connections on a specific port

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I am currently working on a program that establishes TCP and UDP connections between different ports on my computer (thereby simulating a real system). When I kill the main process running, the TCP connections remain open on my computer. So far I have been killing them manually by running `netstat -ano | findstr PID :8080` (assuming 8080 was the port), to get the PIDs and then running `taskkill //PID $pidnum //F` to kill the process. As I am doing this on a few ports I wanted to right a bash script that would do this for me.

To write this script I want to loop through the different ports I am using and save the PIDS in an array and then loop through this array and kill each process. However, I am having difficulty extracting only the PID from the netstat return. The return looks something like this:

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
 TCP    127.0.0.1:50065        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5384
 TCP    [::1]:50057            [::]:0                 LISTENING       6788
```

I have tried `netstat -ano | findstr "PID :8080" | awk '{print $7}'` which should be the PID column but it only returns the column header (PID) but not the actual PID numbers. Any ideas?

Note: I am using the git bash terminal if that makes a difference and as such by default it does not come with commands like lsof.

Comment: Why don't you change the main process so it catches the signal you use to kill it, and it kills all the child processes?

Comment: Good suggestion - i'll look into that. For now though your answer below works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `findstr` command, but there's no need to use another command to search for matching lines, as `awk` can do that by itself.

```
netstat -ano | awk '$1 == "TCP" && $2 ~ /:8080/ { print $5 }'
```